# ios9 / swift2 / xcode7+ AVplayer icecast doesn't process streaming without file extension

Tags: swift, ios9, xcode7, avplayer

how would you play a stream from icecast2 which does not have a file extension

example stream url: http://icecast:8044/channel-123?a=hash

format: mp4a

the code seems to be working on files with an extension, but not on files without.

```
    var player = AVPlayer();
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL:NSURL(string:"http://host/file.mp4a")!);
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem:playerItem)
    let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerController.view.frame = self.view.frame
    playerController.player = player
    self.addChildViewController(playerController)
    self.view.addSubview(playerController.view)
    player.play()
```

EDIT: basically when the stream address ends without the file extension (the file on server is stored without any file extension like .mp3, .mp4,..) the AVPlayer will not play anything(http://example.com/file) ... but if the file name contains the file extension it works properly (http://example.com/file.mp3)

Comment: Hi @MazelTov, are you still looking for answer to this AVPlayer icecast issue?

Comment: yes, do you have some working solution without touching the server side?

Comment: Pretty sure I do. Just working on a POC, then I'll write it up.

Comment: Do you have an example URL for a problematic stream?

Comment: i dont have any public one, sry

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are confusing live streaming and loading media files from server.

If we are talking about live streaming:

1) File extension has no impact on AVPlayer ability to play stream (AVPlayer plays audio from this link, for example: http://icecast.omroep.nl/radio1-bb-aac).

2) Nevertheless, file format is matter (for more information check docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/FrequentlyAskedQuestions/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.html)):

> **What are the specifics of the video and audio formats supported?**
>
> Although the protocol specification does not limit the video and audio formats, the current Apple implementation supports the following formats:
>
> Video:
>   H.264 Baseline Level 3.0, Baseline Level 3.1, Main Level 3.1, and High Profile Level 4.1.
>   Audio:
>   HE-AAC or AAC-LC up to 48 kHz, stereo audio
>   MP3 (MPEG-1 Audio Layer 3) 8 kHz to 48 kHz, stereo audio
>   AC-3 (for Apple TV, in pass-through mode only)

If you have your own server and want to provide ability to streaming audio/video, you need to perform some setup actions as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/DeployingHTTPLiveStreaming/DeployingHTTPLiveStreaming.html).